# FF Full Screen API: keyup event

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a button that I can toggle to call launch  full screen or cancel full screen. Of course, the button has to be updated with change in the looks of the button each time it is toggled. The problem is that whenever ESC key is pressed, the button is not updated in look.

```
  document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) 
                        {
                            console.debug(e.keycode);
                            if (e.keyCode == 27)
                            {
                                btnFS.set("iconClass", "icon_FSlarge");
                                btnFS.set("label", "Set to Full Screen");
                            }
                        }, false);
```

I am not able to capture pressed ESC key.
Please advise. Thanks
Clement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. The solution is FullScreenElement that FullScreen API provides

```
var changeHandler = function() {
 if(document.fullScreenElement||
     document.webkitFullScreenElement||
     document.mozFullScreenElement) {
     alert("In fullscreen, I should do something here");
 } else {
    alert("NOT In fullscreen, I should do something here");
 }
}                       
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
```

Clement

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the other answer, except I fixed some formatting and spelling so that it works...

```
var changeHandler = function(){
    if(document.fullscreenElement||document.webkitFullscreenElement||document.mozFullScreenElement){
        alert("I am fullscreen now");
    }else{
        alert("No longer fullscreen..");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeHandler, false);
```